# CSS animations not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a simple CSS animation to fade in text:

```
#title{
    animation: text 2s;
    -webkit-animation: text 2s;
    -moz-animation: text 2s;
    -o-animation: text 2s;
    font-family: 'Lato300', sans-serif;
    height: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes text{
    0% {display: none;}
    100% {display: inline;}
}

@-moz-keyframes text{
    0% {display: none;}
    100% {display: inline;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes text{
    0% {display: none;}
    100% {display: inline;}
}

@-o-keyframes text{
        0% {display: none;}
    100% {display: inline;}
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="title"><h1>Text goes here</h1></div>
```

For some reason, the animation doesn't play. Does anyone know why?
(I kept all the code incase something else is causing the problem)

Comment: Why no jquery? since css animation doesn't support in all browsers?

Comment: No, it's supported in Safari which is what I'm using. People with older browser are used to the web looking a bit underwhelming and dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to animate `display` property. However you can transition an `opacity`

```
@-webkit-keyframes text {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5FCZA/

Comment: `display` can't be animated. It makes sence because an element can't be partially *hidden*. It is either on a page (`display: block, inline-block`) or not (`display: none`).

Answer (score 0):

```
shake
 @-webkit-keyframes text {
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);}
} 

or rotate
@-webkit-keyframes text {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1);}   
    10%, 20% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotate(-3deg);}
    30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);}
    40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future experiencing a similar issue I solved this by adding

```
display:block
```

to the **span** I was trying to animate